# Java 8: In spite of avoiding terminal operation, see "stream has already been operated upon or closed"

Tags: java-8

The following java 8 stream doesn't have any terminal operation. Isn't the following block supposed to be lazy, since I only have intermediate operation and hasn't been operated yet by a terminal operation. I get "stream has already been operated upon or closed" when I run this block. See https://ideone.com/naR7GB

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("A", "B");
s.map(String::toUpperCase);
s.map(String::toLowerCase);
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:94)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$StatelessOp.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:618)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.map(ReferencePipeline.java:186)
```

Comment: yeah it's weird a bit when you first time see it... s.map.map would not throw that

Answer (score 9):

You need to apply the second `map()` to the mapped instance:

```java
s.map(String::toUpperCase).map(String::toLowerCase);
```

Or

```java
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("A", "B");
Stream<String> s2 = s.map(String::toUpperCase);
Stream<String> s3 = s2.map(String::toLowerCase);
```

As you can only do 1 operation *on the same stream instance*.

But remember, you can only consume `s` once! So either you consume `s2` or `s3`, you can not consume both. That's why we usually write a chained call, since it does not make sense to keep the intermediate objects.

Comment: Good answer, even `s = s.map(String::toUpperCase);` and `s = s.map(String::toLowerCase);` will suffice!